# Новый массив на основе старого

Tags: python

Допустим есть массив:

```
k = \
['A','B','C','D','E','F', 'G','H','I','J',
'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U',
'V','W','X','X','Y','Z']
```

и создадим функцию, которая будет брать наш список *k* и значение, которое будет показывать значение, которое мы отнимаем, чтобя найти область нового массива:

```
def new_list(mylist, x):
 indexes = len(mylist) - 1 
 need_index = indexes - x
 print(need_index)
 need_r = range(0, need_index)
 r_list = list(need_r)
 prin(r_list)
massive(k, 4)

Output: 21
[0, 1, 2, ... , 20]
```

Теперь вопрос: Как закинуть *r_list* в *mylist*? И вообще, правильно ли я это преобразование сделал?)

Comment: Эээ...  `mylist[:-x]` вместо всего этого?

Comment: Это называется срезы - slice, slicing, применяется к индексируемым (subscripted) последовательностям - строкам, спискам, кортежам

Comment: В Python не массивов arrays это списки lists https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: @Hellseher, Ну как-же (Python Collections (Arrays)). Не о чем не говорит?

Answer (score 4):

Используйте **срезы**:

```
print(k[:-1])
# => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'Y']
```

Тут нулевой индекс первого элемента опущен (так как он задан по умолчанию), а индекс последнего элемента -1, то есть выбирается часть списка от первого до последнего элемента *не включая* этот последний элемент.

Визуализация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [дополнительную информацию о срезах на habr.com](https://habr.com/post/30092/):

> Для получения срезов последовательности в Пайтоне принято указывать не номера элементов, а номера «промежутков» между ними. Перед первым элементом последовательности промежуток имеет индекс 0, перед вторым – 1 и так далее. Отрицательные значения отсчитывают элементы с конца строки.
>
> В общем виде срез записывается в следующем виде:
>    `список[начало: конец: шаг]`
>   По умолчанию начало среза равно 0, конец среза равен `len(список)`, шаг равен `1`. 
>   
>  Если шаг не указывается, второй символ «`:`» можно опустить.
>   С помощью среза можно указать подмножество для вставки списка в другой список, даже при нулевой длине. Это удобно для вставки списка в строго определенной позиции.
>
> `<pre>>>>> l = range(12)`
>   `>>> l`
>   `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`
>   `>>> l[1:3]`
>   `[1, 2]`
>   `>>> l[-1:]`
>   `[11]`
>   `>>> l[::2]`
>   `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`
>   `>>> l[0:1]=[-1,-1,-1]`
>   `>>> l`
>   `[-1, -1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`
>   `>>> del l[:3]`
>   `>>> l`
>   `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`